# Not being able to autowire a bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, autowired

I have a DaoImpl of a repository that i want to autowire . The class is like this

```
@Repository("referralDao")
@Transactional(value = "txManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW , readOnly = true)
public class ReferralDaoImpl extends ReferralCommonDao  implements IReferralDao {
    @Override
    public ReferralProperty getReferralProperty(String name) {
        String sQuery = " FROM " + ReferralProperty.class.getSimpleName() + " WHERE name = :name";
        Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery(sQuery);
        query.setParameter("name", name);
        ReferralProperty property = (ReferralProperty)query.uniqueResult();
        return property;
    }
}
```

I further have a controller where I am autowiring this class. The controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="UploadExcel")
public class ExcelController {
       private boolean isMultipart;
   private String filePath;
   private String fileName;
   private int maxFileSize = 50 * 1024;
   private int maxMemSize = 4 * 1024;
   private File file ;
  @Autowired
  private ReferralDaoImpl referralDaoImpl;

  private ReferralProperty referralProperty;

@RequestMapping(value="/excel", method=RequestMethod.GET )
public String excel() {
    return "UploadExcel/excel";
}
@RequestMapping(value="UploadNew" , method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String excel1() {
    return "UploadExcel/excel";
}
@RequestMapping(value = "Upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String doPost (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)  
        throws ServletException, IOException , Exception{  
          isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
          response.setContentType("text/html");
          referralProperty = referralDaoImpl.getReferralProperty("excel.sheet.directory");
          filePath = referralProperty.getValue();
      //    java.io.PrintWriter out = response.getWriter( );
          if( !isMultipart ){
             return "index";
          }
          DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();     
          factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);     
          factory.setRepository(new File("/home/aman"));
          ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);         
          upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );
          try{ 
          List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
          Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();           
          while ( i.hasNext () ) 
          {
             FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
             if ( !fi.isFormField () )  
             {

                String name = fi.getName();
                System.out.println(name +  "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
                referralProperty = referralDaoImpl.getReferralProperty("excel.sheet.name");
                /*referralProperty.setValue(name);
                referralProperty.setDescription(name);
                referralProperty = referralDaoImpl.getReferralProperty("excel.sheet.name");
                System.out.println(referralProperty.getDescription() +  "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");*/
                fileName = referralProperty.getValue();
                if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){
                   file = new File( filePath + 
                   fileName.substring( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
                }else{
                   file = new File( filePath + 
                   fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
                }
                fi.write( file ); 
                processExcel p = new processExcel();
                int p1 = p.Excel();
           //     Excel();
             }
          }    
       }catch(Exception ex) {
           System.out.println(ex);
       }
          return "UploadExcel/downloadexcel";
      }  
@RequestMapping(value = "Download", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void doPost1(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    referralProperty = referralDaoImpl.getReferralProperty("excel.sheet.directory");
    String filepath = referralProperty.getValue();
    referralProperty = referralDaoImpl.getReferralProperty("excel.sheet.name");
    String filename = referralProperty.getValue();
    response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filepath + filename);
    int i;
    while ((i = fileInputStream.read()) != -1) {
        out.write(i);
    }
    fileInputStream.close();
    out.close();
}
public int Excel() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println(referralDaoImpl.toString());
    System.out.println(referralProperty.toString());
    try {
        boolean eligible;
        referralProperty = referralDaoImpl.getReferralProperty("excel.sheet.directory");
        String filepath = referralProperty.getValue();
        referralProperty = referralDaoImpl.getReferralProperty("excel.sheet.name");
        String filename = referralProperty.getValue();
        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(filepath+filename);
         XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(myInput);
         XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
         XSSFRow row = mySheet.getRow(0);
         int emailColumn = 0;
         int eligibilityColumn = row.getLastCellNum();
         for(Cell cell : row) {
             XSSFCell cell1 = (XSSFCell)cell;
             if(cell1.getStringCellValue().equals("email") || cell1.getStringCellValue().equals("Email")) 
             {
                 emailColumn = cell1.getColumnIndex();
                 break;
             }

         }
         XSSFCell cell2 = (XSSFCell)row.createCell(eligibilityColumn);
         cell2.setCellValue("Eligibility");
         for (Row row1 : mySheet)
         {       
             XSSFCell cell1 = (XSSFCell)row1.getCell(emailColumn);
             if(row1.getRowNum()!=0 && cell1!=null) {
             eligible = isValidRefree(cell1.getStringCellValue());
             if(eligible==true)
             {
                 cell2 = (XSSFCell)row1.createCell(eligibilityColumn);
                 cell2.setCellValue("Eligible");
             }
             else
             {
                 cell2 = (XSSFCell)row1.createCell(eligibilityColumn);
                 cell2.setCellValue("InEligible");           
             } 
         }
         }
         myInput.close();
         FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File(filepath+filename));     
         System.out.println(filepath+filename);
         myWorkBook.write(output_file);       
         output_file.close();     

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }   
    return 1;
}

public boolean isValidRefree( String email)
{
    return true;
}

}
```

Here the class gets autowired without any problem and everything works fine. Now if I make another package and a class in it called `processExcel.java` the class looks like this:

```
@Service
public class processExcel {

@Autowired
private ReferralDaoImpl referralDaoImpl;

private ReferralProperty referralProperty;

public int Excel() throws Exception
{

    //System.out.println(referralDaoImpl.toString());
    System.out.println(referralProperty.toString());
    try {
        boolean eligible;
        System.out.println("akjsfbjaksf" + "\n\n\n\n\n");
        referralProperty = referralDaoImpl.getReferralProperty("excel.sheet.directory");
        System.out.println("akjsfbjaksf" + "\n\n\n\n\n");
        String filepath = referralProperty.getValue();
        System.out.println("akjsfbjaksf" + "\n\n\n\n\n");
        referralProperty = referralDaoImpl.getReferralProperty("excel.sheet.name");
        String filename = referralProperty.getValue();
        System.out.println("akjsfbjaksf" + "\n\n\n\n\n");
        FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(filepath+filename);
         XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(myInput);
         XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
         Iterator<Row> rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
         while(rowIter.hasNext()){
             System.out.println("akjsfbjaksf" + "\n\n\n\n\n");
             XSSFRow myRow = (XSSFRow) rowIter.next();
             Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
             if(cellIter.hasNext()) {
                 XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell)cellIter.next();
                 String email = cell.getStringCellValue();
                 eligible = isValidRefree (email);
                 if(eligible == true)
                 {
                     if (cellIter.hasNext()){    
                         XSSFCell cell1 = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                         cell1.setCellValue("Eligible");
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         XSSFCell cell1 = myRow.createCell(1);
                         cell1.setCellValue("Eligible");
                     }

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     if(cellIter.hasNext()){
                         XSSFCell cell1 = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                         cell1.setCellValue("InEligible");
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         XSSFCell cell1 = myRow.getCell(1);
                         cell1.setCellValue("InEligible");
                     }

                 }                       
             }   
         }
         myInput.close();
         FileOutputStream output_file =new FileOutputStream(new File(filepath+"ama.xlsx"));     
         System.out.println(filepath+filename);
         myWorkBook.write(output_file);       
         output_file.close();    

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    return 1;
}

public boolean isValidRefree( String email)
{
        return true;
    }
}
```

and try to autowire `ReferralDaoImpl` it doesn't work and shows `NUllPointerException`. Why is this happening?

Comment: How do you create `processExcel ` class? Is it spring managed?

Comment: Couple of things: First, don't autowire implementations, that is a bad habit. Second, is this new package you create inside a parent package that is being scanned for annotations? Show what your package structure looks like and your config where you define the scan.

Comment: i am using @Service to make it spring managed ? I even tried  Controller and Component and no its a separate package

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz">
  <context:exclude-filter type="regex"
   expression="com\.xyz\.scheduling\..*" />
 </context:component-scan> i am using this to scan the classes and the package name is com.xyz.processExcel

Comment: i am sorry that i can't put the whole package structure and application config

Comment: yes it is . its com.xyz.processExcel

Comment: @EvanRoot Check answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking your code I see that you instantiate your `processExcel` manually in `ExcelController` here `processExcel p = new processExcel();` and that is your problem.

For Spring to be able to autowire anything you need to use the bean created by Spring and when you use `new` to do so, Spring doesn't know anything about this object.

The correct way to use it is autowiring that class as well, and using this bean instead of creating your own:

```
@Autowired
private processExcel processExcel;
```

Just a quick heads up, don't use lowercases for classes names and always autowire the interfaces, not the implementations.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure spring context is initialised and loaded before this class loads.